# Sort contents of Flex ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, flex3

I need to be able to sort the items of a combobox so they will be in alphabetical order.  how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort dataProvider object for your ComboBox.

Sorting methods varies depending what dataProvider data structure is.

For Array you can use [sort()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Array.html#sort%28%29) or [sortOn()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Array.html#sortOn%28%29) methods.
For ArrayCollection check out Sort and SortField classes. I've found example [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/sorting-an-arraycollection-using-the-sortfield-and-sort-classes/).

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array or ArrayCollection that you're using as the dataprovider:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/sorting-an-arraycollection-using-the-sortfield-and-sort-classes/

or

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#sort()